# Regex tested and working in javascript, but breaks in Google Sheet's REGEXEXTRACT

Tags: javascript, regex, google-sheets

I've tested this regex to extract URLs from a text string:

```
(?:(?:https?|ftp|file):\/\/|www\.|ftp\.)(?:\([-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|$?!:,.]*\)|[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|$?!:,.])*(?:\([-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|$?!:,.]*\)|[A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|$])
```

... and it works just as I'd like, it matches all the URLs I throw at it.

However, when I use REGEXEXTRACT in Google Sheets like this:

```
=iferror(Regexextract(A1,"(?:(?:https?|ftp|file):\/\/|www\.|ftp\.)(?:\([-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|$?!:,.]*\)|[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|$?!:,.])*(?:\([-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|$?!:,.]*\)|[A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|$])"),"")
```

... nothing extracts. The regex is identical.

What am I doing wrong?

NB. The Regex was tested here: http://www.regextester.com/53716

Comment: Google Sheets [documenation](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098245?hl=en) states: 
***Google products use [RE2](https://github.com/google/re2/blob/master/doc/syntax.txt) for regular expressions. [Learn how to use RE2 expressions](https://github.com/google/re2/blob/master/doc/syntax.txt).***

Comment: I would at least replace all those `[-` by `[\-` since `-` has special meaning in a character class, it's better to escape a dash in a character class. Unless it's at the end of the character class (in most regex engines)

Comment: @LukStorms `-`   has no special meaning if placed at the beginning or at the end of a character set. `[-abc]` or `[abc-]` are totally valid.

Comment: @PedroLobito OK. Even javascript is ok with a dash at the beginning. But it's still not a bad practise to escape a dash anyway if it's not used for a range.

Comment: @LukStorms, the good practice is knowing the rules and use them as necessary, not more not less.

Comment: Isn't it enough to find `http` etc "prefix" and then match any non-whitespace char? `=REGEXEXTRACT(B6, "(?:(?:https?|ftps?|file)://|www\.|ftp\.)\S+")`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you use a simpler regex like

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(B6, "(?:(?:https?|ftps?|file)://|www\.|ftp\.)\S+")
```

**Details**:

- `(?:(?:https?|ftps?|file)://|www\.)` - either of:

  - `(?:https?|ftps?|file)://` - `http`/`https`, `ftp`/`ftps` or `file` followed with `://`
  - `|` - or
  - `www\.` - `www.`
- `\S+` - 1 or more non-whitespace symbols

[image]

Comment: Excellent! There are a few exceptions your regex doesn't catch, but it still just saved me hours of work. Thank you very much :)